# Two questions on strategies for quantifier elimination

Tags: equation-solving

With the help of people here I was able to solve several cases similar to IC3 but this case - unlike the other cases - does not return an answer. I will try to run it for a day with 8 processors but will be grateful for:

1. Any suggestions on how to solve IC3 (besides more memory or more time)
2. In the end I only care about some other constraints so would help resolve if I add additional constraints on the other variables (a, c and d)
   when trying to eliminate x and z?

   ```
   IC3 := (4 d^3 + 24 a d^2 x + 3 (2 a + c) d (-c x^2 + 2 a (x^2 + 4 x z - 2 z^2)) - (2 a + c)^2 (c x^3 + 4 a (x^3 - 3 x^2 z + z^3)))/(6 (2 a + c)^2) 
           && 0 < -((2 d)/(2 a + c)) < 1
   Resolve[{x,z}, (-(2 d)/(2 a + c)) <= x <= 1, (-d/(2 a + c))<=z<=(-(2 d)/(2 a + c)), IC3]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but my guess what is going wrong. Feel free to edit it.

My guess is that **Mathematica has problems when the solution is lower dimensional and/or empty**.

The polynomial inequality described by IC3 can be expressed as F[x,z] >=0 for some F function. Say we find the region of parameters {a,b,c} such that it holds true for all x and for z == -d/(2 a + c)) or z == -2d/(2 a + c)). That is, for z at the boundary, we have a region of {a,b,c} where the inequality is true. If the inequality where to reverse for an *interior* z then the derivative with respect to z must be zero, D[F[x,z],z]==0, the second derivative must be non-negative (local-minimum), D[F[x,z],z,z]>=0.

If we try to solve D[F[x,z],z]==0 and  D[F[x,z],z,z]>0 in the region where x and z are, we get an empty solution. If we try to solve  D[F[x,z],z]==0 and  D[F[x,z],z,z]==0 we get some solutions where a==0 (*i.e.* a lower dimensional set)